# How do I programmatically draw to a display in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uikit, core-graphics

I have a method of drawing to the screen that has many benefits for my application except for the small issue that it doesn't work... at all.

I have an iOS program with a UIImageView widget and I'm trying to programmatically draw into it but it just looks black when I run the program.  This is the outlet declaration in my header file:

```
@interface TestViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@end
```

...and this is my implementation:

```
@implementation TestViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(400, 400), YES, 0.0);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGFloat colour[] = { 1, 0, 0, 1 };
    CGContextSetFillColor(context, colour);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 400));

    self.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [self.imageView setNeedsDisplay];

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

`TestViewController` is the delegate for the view controller and `imageView` is the outlet for the `UIImageView` widget.  I try to draw a 400 x 400 red box into an image and assign that image to the widget.  I even call `setNeedsDisplay` for good measure.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These lines are the problem:

```
CGFloat colour[] = { 1, 0, 0, 1 };
CGContextSetFillColor(context, colour);
```

Delete them. Instead, set the fill color this way:

```
 CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
```

The reason for your issue is that you were failing to create a color space. You needed to have called `CGContextSetFillColorSpace`, and you failed to do so. But that's needed only if you use `CGContextSetFillColor`. But it's deprecated, so don't use it. Use `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor`, as the docs recommend. It takes care of the color space issue for you.